# XSLT Transformation of Hyperlinks

Tags: html, xml, xslt, hyperlink

I have an XSLT web page that transforms a table I have extracted from MS Access. In the xml document I have some hyperlinks such as **C:\My Work\My HTML test.htm** and as far as I know the white space is preserved. My problem is that when I transform this to a Hyperlink the link changes to **file:///C:\My%20Work\My%20HTML%20test.htm** which does not work. I have other links that are formed in the normal way (without spaces) that work fine so I can pinpoint the issue to the addition of the %20.

I have the command:

```
<xsl:preserve-space elements="clmAttach1Link clmAttach2Link"/>
```

in the XSL document. The code to transform the XML is:

```
<a>
 <xsl:attribute name="href">
  <xsl:value-of select="clmAttach1Link"/>
 </xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:value-of select="clmAttach2Name"/>
</a>
```

This code displays all of the information correctly just does not link to the local files.

Can anyone help me transform the hyperlinks to retain the spaces so I can link to local files?

Thanks

Comment: Show the input XML document and show a complete XSLT stylesheet. Make it more clear what the expected output should be. More help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: What is the output method of your stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

What is the correct link suppose to be? Should it be with spaces? else you could try to use:

```
<xsl:strip-space>
```

And have a path without spaces.

Comment: The links are to local files and they include spaces. Unfortunately the server they sit on has spaces in its name so I can't just ask the users to change the file naming format. So the correct link will include spaces like C:\My Work\My HTML test.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces in URLs is not considered safe, but you can try using `<xsl:text>`:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;a href="</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="clmAttach1Link"/>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">"></xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="clmAttach2Name"/>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/a></xsl:text>
```

or only `value-of` and `concat`:

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat(
    '&lt;a href=&quot;', clmAttach1Link, '&quot;>', clmAttach2Name ,'&lt;/a>')"/>
```

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Yes, to a degree, with output method="html" on e.g. http://www.xslfiddle.net/ outputted link is: href="C:%5CMy%20Work%5CMy%20HTML%20test.htm"

Comment: Well, then why don't you simply change the output method to "xml", instead of this horrible hack?

Comment: Because I assumed it needed to be html, but I may have been wrong. Good point, @michael.hor257k :-)